# How to get elements by other attributes with router in express?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm new to express and trying to build a restful api that get the elements by other attributes instead of id.

In the tutorials I found, they usually get elements by id, example code could be:

```
router.route('/something/:something_id')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Something.findById(req.params.something_id, function(err, something) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(something);
        });
    });
```

And the schema could be like:

```
var SomethingSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    color: String
});
```

But I'm trying to get by some other attribute, like

```
router.route('/something/:something_color')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        // get all somethings with color = something_color
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn `mongodb` and or `mongoose`, it is actually pretty straitforward. There is `Schema.find` function which does exactly what you want to do.

```
router.route('/something/:something_color')

.get(function(req, res) {
    // get all somethings with color = something_color
    Something.find({ color: req.params.something_color }, function(err, something) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(something);
    });
});
```

I just searched mongodb express on google and first page I found this tutorial: https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I should read mongodb and mongoose document. I was trying to find an answer in the express document.